# extracting twitter video with R

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

I have a video in my local folder.
What i want to do is the use **rtweet**  or any pther *R* package to search the twitter for this specific video and pull the data as a data frame.

IS there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There’s no way to do this via, for example, video fingerprinting - Twitter search does not support that. If you knew a specific URL where that video is shared from, you could search for it in the API.

Comment: Thank you, Andy Piper!